# Error trying to call find from perl

Tags: find, perl

```
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $srceDir = "//mnt/Share_Drive/Verizon PM&T/Capture Files/";
opendir(DIR, $srceDir) or die "Can't open $srceDir: $!";
my @files = (find -type f -newermt "12 Feb 2013", $srceDir);
closedir(DIR);
```

I can run the `find` command with the `-newermt` option in Linux just fine but when I put it in the perl script I got the errors below, could you help?  Thanks

```
String found where operator expected at ./queryAlm.pl line 11, near "newermt "12 Feb 2013""
  (Do you need to predeclare newermt?)
syntax error at ./queryAlm.pl line 11, near "newermt "12 Feb 2013""
```

Comment: My 2 cents: it has nothing to do with find, it has to do with you quoting the command improperly.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas is right, the way your script is written you are trying to use the system's `find` instead of the perl module you previously imported.

Answer (score 2):

The `File::Find` perl module has little if any to do with the `find` command. See `perldoc File::Find` for how to use it.

As jordanm points out, you can use `find2perl` to help you write that `perl` code, but please note that `find2perl` only recognises the standard `find` syntax, so typically not BSD/GNU extensions like `-newermt`. You'll have to write the perl code by your self (call `stat()` for the file and compare the `mtime` with `POSIX::mktime(0,0,0,12,2,113)`).

To run the `find` command, you don't need the `File::Find` module, you can simply do:

```
my $srceDir = "//mnt/Share_Drive/Verizon PM&T/Capture Files/";
my @find_cmd = ("find", $srceDir, "-type", "f", "-newermt", "12 Feb 2013", "-print0");

open FIND, "-|", @find_cmd;
$/ = "\0";
my @files = <FIND>; chomp @files;
my $ret = close FIND or warn $! ?
    "Error closing find pipe: $!" :
    "find exited with non-zero exit status: $?";
```

Comment: `File::Find` does come with a `find2perl` script that can generate perl code from your `find` command.

Comment: Actually, I would like to incorporate the unix command find into my perl script.  I tried the following code:                   my $srceDir = "//mnt/Share_Drive/Verizon PM&T/Capture Files/";

my $find_cmd = 'find $srceDir -type f -newermt 2013-02-14 ! -newermt 2013-02-15';

open(FIND_FILE, "$find_cmd |");
while(<FIND_FILE>){ 
    next if /^total/;
    print $_; 
}

Comment: @oanh, please update your question (click [`edit`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/64698/edit) under it)